# Instead of roles how can we pass custom permissions in ngx-permission

Tags: angular

How can we set custom permissions instead of role based one in angular 4 using ngx-permission . I am trying to check the current logged in user has the permission to create a customer.

```js
export const CustomerRouting: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: CustomerComponent,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      data: {
        breadcrumb: 'Customers'
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: 'add',
          component: CustomerAddComponent,
          canActivate: [NgxPermissionsGuard],
          data: {
            breadcrumb: 'Add',
            status: true,
            permissions: {
              only: 'addCustomer',
              redirectTo: {
                addCustomer: 'CustomerAddComponent',
                default: 'login'
              }
            }
          }
        },
```

This will redirect me to 404. Will this implementation is correct ?

Comment: A small code example might be useful for future readers and answerers to understand your issue.